# Should I hard wrap lines in Org documents?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to use org mode for writing rather than keeping track of my day-to-day activities. By writing I mean to "take notes" from books by copy and pasting entire paragraphs that I find relevant.

```
#+TITLE: Title of the book

* Chapter 1
  Chapter one notes here...                        should I wrap at 78?

* Chapter 2
  Chapter two notes here...                        should I wrap at 78?
```

Hard wrapping the lines at 78 characters makes text easier to scan for the eyes and I can see the same result if I use something outside emacs such as `cat` or `less`.

However I read that Org doesn't wrap because it makes tables look ugly. I don't know what's the truth. I would be grateful for any suggestion. I don't know how should I proceed, should I wrap or not?

UPDATE:

I started using something like this:

```
; Org Mode
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda nil
          (auto-fill-mode 1)
          (set-fill-column 78)))
```

Comment: I hard wrap text (but not tables, code blocks etc) and I have had zero problems.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds great. How do you wrap only text? Do you have a specific setting in init.el?

Comment: Manually with `M-q` (aka `org-fill-paragraph`).

Comment: I updated my post. I'm using `auto-fill-mode` it seems to work fine.

Comment: *"... because it makes tables look ugly"* - but your examples don't even use tables?! You can wrap lines in normal text without problems but leave tables unfilled.